# wp query to display pages only

Tags: wordpress

The custom wp query below shows posts and pages regardles of the argument in the query set to page only

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'category_name' => 'somecategory'

    ));

    if($query->have_posts()):
    while($query->have_posts()):
        $query->the_post();
        the_title();
    endwhile;
    endif;
```

I must note that in my setup posts and pages share the same categories. I want to query only pages but this query returns both posts and pages of the set category.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, pages don't support "categories" taxonomy. So, there is no need to add **'category_name' => 'somecategory'**.

Your code is getting all the pages plus all the posts in the category you're referring. That's why, you're seeing pages + posts.

If you only want to get pages, use the code below:

```
    $query = new WP_Query(array(
     'post_type' => 'page',
    ));
    if($query->have_posts()):
     while($query->have_posts()):
      $query->the_post();
        the_title();
     endwhile;
    endif;
```

Comment: I added category support for pages as described here https://thewphosting.com/add-categories-tags-pages-wordpress/

Comment: Try with cat -> cat_id OR category_name -> category_slug.

Comment: A common pitfall is the fact that:

category_name takes the category SLUG NOT the name as attribute

This is often mistaken.